# Laravel login does nothing

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am using Laravel 6 and my login doesn't work.
I started with `php artisan make:auth` and tested the login. It worked. Then I made a custom login page. My problem is that my custom login page doesn't work. When I click login it just reloads the page without doing anything. Can I debug it somehow? Here is my code of login.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<title>{{ config('app.name', 'CMS Buddy') }}</title>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Fonts -->
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fd2bd3b3b6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="limiter">
<div class="container-login100" style="background-image: url('img/background_login.jpg');">
    <div class="wrap-login100 p-t-190 p-b-30">
        <form class="login100-form validate-form" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
            @csrf
            <div class="login100-form-avatar">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
            </div>
            <span class="login100-form-title p-t-20 p-b-45">
                    CMS Buddy
                </span>
            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-10 {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid': '' }}"
                 data-validate="E-Mail address is required">
                <input class="input100" type="text" name="email" placeholder="{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                <span class="symbol-input100">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    </span>
                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                @endif
            </div>

            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-10" data-validate="Password is required">
                <input class="input100" type="password" name="{{ __('Password') }}"
                       placeholder="{{ __('Password') }}">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                <span class="symbol-input100">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                    </span>
                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                @endif
            </div>

            <div class="container-login100-form-btn p-t-10">
                <button type="submit" class="login100-form-btn">
                    {{ __('Login') }}
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center w-full p-t-25 p-b-230">
                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                    <a class="txt1" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                    </a>
                @endif
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="{{ asset('js/login/select2.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/login/main.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page doesn't reload, it's redirecting back for failed validation....
Why?
Because you're missing the password field in your form
Change

```html
name="{{ __('Password') }}"
```

to

```html
name="password"
```

The  [__()](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-__)    function is useful to localize or translate text for your users, however the name attribute is not rendered* in the browser so it doesn't need to be localized..
Laravel expects the form to post `email` and `password`

Answer (score 2):

I think your password cause these. The validation will return probably "The password field is required".

Mispelled capital "P" for password name attribute.

Change these:

```
<input class="input100" type="password" name="{{ __('Password') }}" placeholder="{{ __('Password') }}">
```

To these:

```
<input class="input100" type="password" name="{{ __('password') }}" placeholder="{{ __('Password') }}">
```

Comment: You're still localizing the password, what if the page is loaded in Chinese? it would be `<input class="input100" type="password" name="密碼">`

Comment: Yes your answer is "technically" correct, and respect is mutual across everybody on this site, regardless of reputation